# Custom search query on Wordpress page not working

Tags: php, wp-query

I have made a custom page for an university website where all the available scholarships are listed. User can specify city, degree, intake, scholarship type and language to search for universities with available scholarships. For this I've used advanced custom field and custom post type UI plugins and added custom fields to get data from the admin. I've tried to show the data in a tabular form in that page and it is showing the way I want to. But the problem is when i try to use the filter option for any of the above criteria(city, degree, intake, scholarship type and language) I'm getting no results but the table remains the same (The table should show only the filtered data, but it isn't). I tried checking the `$args` and all the selected parameters are there. I suspect there is some problem with the `$query` variable because when i checked it had all the posts data. you can check the output results here https://pastebin.com/Xgmja3Yj

here's my code

```
<?php

/**
 * Template Name: Scholarship Page
 *
 * @package HelloElementor
 */

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
  exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

get_header();

?>


<div class="container">
  <h4 class="lesson-title">Browse and Apply for Scholarships</h4>
  <form action="#" method="get">

    <select name="city">
      <!-- <option value="">Select city/province</option> -->
      <option value="zhejiang">Zhejiang</option>
      <option value="zhengzhou">Zhengzhou</option>
      <option value="tshinghua">Tshinghua</option>
      <option value="peking">Peking</option>
    </select>

    <select name="scholarship_type">
      <option value="partial">Partial</option>
      <option value="full">Full</option>
    </select>

    <select name="degree">
      <option value="bachelor">Bachelor</option>
      <option value="masters">Masters</option>
      <option value="phd">PHD</option>
    </select>

    <select name="language">
      <option value="">Select Language</option>
      <option value="english">English</option>
      <option value="chinese">Chinese</option>
    </select>

    <select name="intake">
      <option value="">Select Intake</option>
      <option value="summer">Summer</option>
      <option value="winter">Winter</option>
      <option value="autumn">Autumn</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="">Search</button>
  </form>

<?php
if ($_GET['city'] && !empty($_GET['city'])) {
  $city = $_GET['city'];
}

if ($_GET['scholarship_type'] && !empty($_GET['scholarship_type'])) {
  $scholarship_type = $_GET['scholarship_type'];
}

if ($_GET['degree'] && !empty($_GET['degree'])) {
  $degree = $_GET['degree'];
}

if ($_GET['language'] && !empty($_GET['language'])) {
  $language = $_GET['language'];
}

if ($_GET['intake'] && !empty($_GET['intake'])) {
  $intake = $_GET['intake'];
}
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'scholarships',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  // 'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => "OR",
    array(
      'key' => 'cityprovince',
      'value' => $city,
      'compare' => '='
    ),

    array(
      'key' => 'scholarship',
      'value' => $scholarship_type,
      'compare' => '='
    ),

    array(
      'key' => 'degree',
      'value' => $degree,
      'compare' => '='
    ),

    array(
      'key' => 'language',
      'value' => $language,
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),

    array(
      'key' => 'intake',
      'value' => $intake,
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
  )
);
  
  $query = new WP_Query($args);
  
  // echo var_dump($args);
  // echo "<br>";
  // echo "<br>";
  ?>
  <div class="post clearfix">
    <table style="width:100%">
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>City/Province</th>
        <th>Major</th>
        <th>Program ID</th>
        <th>Degree</th>
        <th>Language</th>
        <th>Intake</th>
        <th>Scholarship</th>
        <th>Total Amount</th>
      </tr>
      <?php
      while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
      //echo var_dump($query);
      ?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
          <td><?php the_field('cityprovince'); ?></td>
          <td><?php the_field('major'); ?></td>
          <td><?php the_field('program_id'); ?></td>
          <td><?php the_field('degree'); ?></td>
          <td><?php the_field('language'); ?></td>
          <td><?php the_field('intake'); ?></td>
          <td><?php the_field('scholarship'); ?></td>
          <td><?php the_field('total_amount'); ?></td>
        </tr>
      <?php endwhile;
      wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The `key` in `meta_query` are the field name in ACF. So any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have 6 posts in your scholarships post type?

Comment: @anton yes...if i add new post it is getting added to the table so no problem in there

Comment: Pretty interesting. Did you tried to add arrays into `meta_query` one by one, strating from the city, to see if wp_query will give you different result.

Comment: @anton I just tried with one single query that is matching only the `$city`. It is working now. But when using the multiple parameters like language, degree it is not working. Also I had to fix some letter casing problem. But atleast it is working with one query. Idk why it is not working with multiple

Comment: Alright i get it now. The problem is as i set the relation to "OR" because of that it is showing all the results in the table regardless of the other parameters. So if i set one parameter it is working for that but when i set 2 or 3 for example `degree` it is fetching all the matched values. As all the fields have `bachelor` the table is showing all the entries regardless of the `city` or other variables. So I think i have to do some work here

Comment: As I thought earlier the `wp_query` is ok, because it's returning object depending on your criteria. So right now `relation => 'OR'` it gets post if it has at least one of your 5 criterias. If you just need to match all five criteries you need to change relation to `AND`. But if you need something more complex you can do this as well, because starting with wp version 4.1, meta_query clauses can be nested in order to construct complex queries.

Comment: By the way, do not send raw data to `wp_query`, use sanitization first for security reason. For example `$city = $_GET['city']` should be `$city = sanitize_text_field($_GET['city'])` , more on this - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/theme-security/data-sanitization-escaping/

Comment: @anton got it thanks for the insight.